# Excel dependent dynamic lists based on Teacher Name

Tags: excel, list

So I have a sheet with 2 tables (being retrieved from a SQL Query): Teachers and TeacherSets.

Teachers Table (single column):

```
(Header) Teachers 
         Teacher1
         Teacher2
         Teacher3
```

TeacherSets Table (2 columns):

```
Header    Teacher    Set
          Teacher1   ABC
          Teacher2   XYZ
          Teacher1   GHI
          Teacher2   AAA
```

I am already using Teachers to retrieve a dropdown list but what I'd like to do is create another list that once I've selected the teacher from the first drop down, it only allows me to select only the matching sets for that teacher from table TeacherSets.

Selecting Teacher1 would only allow me to see ABC and GHI in the corresponding dropdown list.

I've had a read around and most of the solutions refer to selection based on lookups to multiple columns with defined names but this is slightly different or is it not?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I've used this ability of Excel with named cell ranges and data validation rules using an INDIRECT forumla.

Here is a link to a sample with your data: [click](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3y3o-BY2YG7V0RPQzNYdUo0T3c/view?usp=sharing)

1. Create lists of the Teachers and of each teacher's sets.

   ```
   Teachers        Teacher1    Teacher2
   Teacher1        ABC         XYZ
   Teacher2        GHI         AAA
   Teacher3
   ```
2. Give the lists names

For each list, select the values, then select from menu

**Formulas - Defined Names group - Define Name**

The name should be equal to the column header (i.e. Teachers, Teacher1, Teacher2) and include the values of the list.

3. Add data validation to Teacher and Set columns

Select the cells of the column, then select from menu:

**Data - Data Tools group - Data Validation**

[image: Adding data validation to Teachers]

For the Set column the formula I used is =INDIRECT($F$10) referring to the first cell in the Teacher column.

[image: Adding data validation to Set]

That should do it. Hope it works for you.

Comment: This is the dedication to site that SO needs from new users.  It must've taken a while to build the model to show screen shots of data validation dialogues.  Take a bow.

Comment: Hi @Nad HR, So I probably should have mentioned. The TeacherSets table cannot be separated into separate lists as you have done because the base data is being retrieved from a SQL query and is likely to change.

Thanks for taking so much time into the reply though.